# Haskell: Beginner syntax question

Tags: haskell, syntax, indentation

a very simple question from a Haskell learner. I am working through [Yet Another Haskell Tutorial](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/Haskell/YAHT) and I am stuck on a simple syntax practice. The code given below: When I copy and paste it (from pdf) and then adjust the indentation it works fine, but when I type it out into an editor (in my case Notepad++) then it throws the following error:

```
Guess.hs:8:9: parse error on input ´hSetBuffering´
```

I made sure that I did not mix tabs and whitespaces (4 whitespaces) and I did not find a typo in the book. I am sure it is a very simple mistake so thanks for any input.

Nebelhom

Here is the code:

```
module Main
    where

import IO
import Random

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdin LineBuffering
    num <- randomRIO (1::Int, 100)
    putStrLn "I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100"
    doGuessing num

doGuessing num = do
    putStrLn "Enter your guess:"
    guess <- getLine
    let guessNum = read guess
    if guessNum < num
        then do putStrLn "Too low!"
                doGuessing num
    else if read guess > num
        then do putStrLn "Too high!"
                doGuessing num
    else do putStrLn "You Win!"
```

Comment: I tried your code with ghc and it worked just fine.

Comment: You might want to use something a *little* more advanced than Notepad. I use Notepad++ but there are plenty of other editors out there which are loved by programmers...

Comment: @MatrixFrog: I use Notepad++ ...

I tend to use IDEs but the laptop I currently use is rather slow so I stick to programs that are not resource hungry. Eclipse and Netbeans for example nearly kill the performance of the laptop.

Answer (score 3):

There's no syntax error that I can see, or reproduce:

```
$ ghci A.hs
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.
Loading package ffi-1.0 ... linking ... done.
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( A.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
```

which means it is probably tabs. Did you insert a tab somewhere? And then use 4 spaces for indenting? Tabs are in general a bad idea in Haskell, as they lead to unintentional, and unintelligible, syntax errors.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something as simple as that. I always started with 4 whitespaces and Notepad then automatically indented with a tab. Switched that right off ;)

Comment: I have been consistently using ONLY tabs to indent Haskell, Python, C++, and bash, for years. N tab characters express what I want more clearly (N levels of indentation). I can never have a non-integer indentation level. The amount of physical space shown on the screen for each tab character (level of indentation) can be configured in an editor, and need not be hard-coded into the source file, where I feel it does not belong.